# CameraUI and CameraRoll in ADOBE AIR Crash application on IOS device when release

Tags: ios, air

I am using  cameraUI to take a picture and use it and also using CameraRoll to use existing image from device.Every thing work well in debug but on release my application crash and reach to Home screen of IPAD .

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing your app with the latest version of AIR SDK from labs.adobe.com

Comment: Currently i am using Adobe AIR SDK & Compiler (version 15.0.0.356)

Comment: there is no any release on on October 22, 2014. but the current version of AIR is 16 beta .Would it better to use beta version

Comment: Yes. Try using the latest SDK, whatever the number is now.